# Move item in array to the top in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to remove an item from one array and then put it into the top of another array.

I currently have an array of articles a few of these articles have type hero is true and the others are just regular. I need to find the first hero article in the array and remove it. Then put this article into the top of  another array. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

I currently have this:

```
articles = [
    {title: "article 1", hero: false},
    {title: "article 2", hero: false},
    {title: "article 3", hero: true},
    {title: "article 4", hero: false},
    {title: "article 5", hero: true},
    {title: "article 6", hero: false},
    {title: "article 7", hero: true}
]
```

But want this result:

```
articles = [
    {title: "article 1", hero: false},
    {title: "article 2", hero: false},
    {title: "article 4", hero: false},
    {title: "article 5", hero: true},
    {title: "article 6", hero: false},
    {title: "article 7", hero: true}
]

hero = [
    {title: "article 3", hero: true}
]
```

Comment: You should look at [Array.prototype.findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) and [Array.prototype.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Comment: `hero = articles.filter(articles.hero => true); hero = hero[0]`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const articles = [
    {title: "article 1", hero: false},
    {title: "article 2", hero: false},
    {title: "article 3", hero: true},
    {title: "article 4", hero: false},
    {title: "article 5", hero: true},
    {title: "article 6", hero: false},
    {title: "article 7", hero: true},
];

const heros = [];

for(let [i, article] of articles.entries())
{
  if(article.hero)
    {
    heros.unshift(article);
    articles.splice(i, 1);
    break;
    }
}

console.log(heros);
console.log(articles);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`.findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) to get the first article with hero equal to `true`. You can then use this index to add the object to your `hero` array, and then use it again to remove from your `articles` array by using [`.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

See example below:

```js
const articles = [
    {title: "article 1", hero: false},
    {title: "article 2", hero: false},
    {title: "article 3", hero: true},
    {title: "article 4", hero: false},
    {title: "article 5", hero: true},
    {title: "article 6", hero: false},
    {title: "article 7", hero: true}
];
const hero = [];
const foundArticle = articles.findIndex(({hero}) => hero);
hero.push(articles[foundArticle]);
articles.splice(foundArticle, 1);

console.log(articles);
console.log(hero);
```

For IE support you can manually find the index instead of using `.findIndex()`:

```js
function findObjInArr(arr, cb) {
  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let obj = arr[i];
    if(cb(obj)) {
      return i;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}

const articles = [
    {title: "article 1", hero: false},
    {title: "article 2", hero: false},
    {title: "article 3", hero: true},
    {title: "article 4", hero: false},
    {title: "article 5", hero: true},
    {title: "article 6", hero: false},
    {title: "article 7", hero: true}
];

const hero = [];
const foundArticle = findObjInArr(articles, function(obj) {
  return obj.hero;
});
hero.push(articles[foundArticle]);
articles.splice(foundArticle, 1);

console.log(articles);
console.log(hero);
```

Comment: `findIndex` is not supported by IE https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex#Browser_compatibility

Comment: @Dónal there are a lot of things not supported by IE. I find that it's not worth bringing it up, unless the question shows that this is relevant information. Otherwise it's easy enough to just check if stuff is supported and if it isn't, then use an alternative.

Comment: splice returns an array of the removed elements. If it is clear, that there is an element, which fulfills the condition, then `const hero = articles.splice(articles.findIndex(({hero}) => hero), 1);` should suffice. If it is not certain there will be a match, there will be bugs (for the first parameter of splice, "If negative, it will begin that many elements from the end of the array", and if nothing is found, findIndex returns -1). Then, at least one "if" will be required.

Comment: @Dónal I've added an IE (hopefully) supported version.

Comment: @ASDFGerte yes, if there is no item found `-1` will be returned by `findIndex`. But I think error handling is out of the scope of the original question.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var articles = [
    {title: "article 1", hero: false},
    {title: "article 2", hero: false},
    {title: "article 3", hero: true},
    {title: "article 4", hero: false},
    {title: "article 5", hero: true},
    {title: "article 6", hero: false},
    {title: "article 7", hero: true}
];
    
// Get the index of the first hero article, findIndex is not supported by IE 
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex#Browser_compatibility
var heroIndex = articles.findIndex(function (article) {
    return article.hero;
});

var hero = [];

if (heroIndex > -1) {
    // remove the first hero article from articles and add it to a new array
    hero = articles.splice(heroIndex, 1);
}

console.log("Hero article", hero);
console.log("Other articles", articles);
```

Comment: simply, `hero = articles.splice(...)`

Answer (score 0):

```js
articles = [
    {title: "article 1", hero: false},
    {title: "article 2", hero: false},
    {title: "article 4", hero: false},
    {title: "article 5", hero: true},
    {title: "article 6", hero: false},
    {title: "article 7", hero: true}
]
result = []

for(var article of articles) {
    if (article.hero) {
    articles.splice(articles.indexOf(article))
    result.push(article)
    }

}
console.log(articles)
console.log(result)
```

Comment: it looks like he wants the first article of hero that is true.

Comment: That's not removing anything, nor adding anything.

Comment: What? I do not understand, I add the first object to an array when the hero is true?

Comment: Okay, I understand I don't remove anything, easy edit though

Comment: Now removes from the first array, add to another.

Answer (score 0):

You can try as,

```js
let articles = [
    {title: "article 1", hero: false},
    {title: "article 2", hero: false},
    {title: "article 3", hero: true},
    {title: "article 4", hero: false},
    {title: "article 5", hero: true},
    {title: "article 6", hero: false},
    {title: "article 7", hero: true}
];

let hero = [];
let heroArticle = {};

for(let article of articles){
  if(article.hero){
    heroArticle = article;
    hero.push(article);
    break;
    }
}

articles = articles.filter(a => a.title !== heroArticle.title);

console.log(articles);
```

Answer (score 0):

like this?

```
var hero = []
var founds = articles.find((e)=>{
  return e.hero ? e: false
})
hero.unshift(founds)
```

Answer (score -3):

First, pick the third element for articles array -

articles[2];

define an empty array name Hero -

let Hero = [] or Hero = new Array();

then push -

hero.push(articles[2]);

Comment: It's not what OP wanted and `Hero` is different variable than `hero`